# Python pro way to make an abstract class allowing each child class to define its own attributes, Python3

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class

I have to model several cases, each case is realised by a `class`. I want to make sure that each `class` must have 2 methods `get_input()` and `run()`. So in my opinion, I can write a `CaseBase` class where these 2 methods are decorated as `@abstractmethod`. Therefore, any child class has to implement these 2 methods. And this is exactly my goal.

However, due to the nature of my work, each case is for distinct subject, and it is not easy to define a fixed group of attributes. The attributes should be defined in the `__init__` method of a `class`. That means I don't know what exactly attributes to write in the `CaseBase` class. All I know is that all children cases must have some common attributes, like `self._common_1` and `self._common_2`.

Therefore, my idea is that I also decorate the `__init__` method of `CaseBase` class by `@abstractmethod`. See my code below.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Dict, List


class CaseBase(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        self._common_1: Dict[str, float] = {}
        self._common_2: List[float] = []
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def get_input(self, input_data: dict):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        ...


class CaseA(CaseBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self._common_1: Dict[str, float] = {}
        self._common_2: List[float] = []
        self._a1: int = 0
        self._a2: str = ''

    def get_input(self, input_data: dict):
        self._common_1 = input_data['common_1']
        self._common_2 = input_data['common_2']
        self._a1 = input_data['a1']
        self._a2 = input_data['a2']

    def run(self):
        print(self._common_1)
        print(self._common_2)
        print(self._a1)
        print(self._a2)


def main():
    case_a = CaseA()
    case_a.get_input(input_data={'common_1': {'c1': 1.1}, 'common_2': [1.1, 2.2], 'a1': 2, 'a2': 'good'})
    case_a.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My question: Is my way a good Python style?

I followed many Python tutorials about how to make Abstract class and child class. They all give examples where a fixed group of attributes are defined in the `__init__` method of the base class. I also see some approach to use `super().__init__` code in the child class to change the attributes defined in the base class or to add new attributes. But I am not sure if it is better (more pro) than my way.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it intentional that the attributes use private naming? An ABC usually describes an *outwards* interface, not implementation details like private attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mostly used the `abc` module in python 3.10 correctly. but it doesn't make sense to decorate the constructor with `@abstractmethod`. It's unnecessary. Each class, derived or not, can and will have its own constructor. You can call `super().__init__(args)` within the child class to call the constructor of its immediate parent if you didn't want to duplicate its code but wanted to do further initialization in the child class constructor.